# how can i open png and jpg files with python?

Tags: python, image, png, jpeg

i need a program to open png files. I found this on the internet, but this gives me an error.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("D:/foto's/fbshare.png")

im.show()
```

this is the error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'open' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

does anybody have the solution to this problem?

Comment: Do you have another file with the same name in there?

Comment: try import PIL.Image

Comment: or try just - import Image; if needed pip install image first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `matplotlib.image` as `mpimg` and `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image_path = "D:/foto's/fbshare.png"
image = mpimg.imread(image_path)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Comment: it gives me this error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.mpimg'

Comment: Done! Yes, I mixed mpimg with the real name `matplotlib.image`.

Comment: i am sorry, yes it did it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to name the file the same as any of the modules being imported in that file.

read more in the example here:

https://geektechstuff.com/2020/06/13/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-has-no-attribute-python/